# CS0006 error while trying to set up CruiseControl.net

Tags: c#, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

We are trying to set up CC.Net. We have CS0006 error saying that DLL is missing in `xxx\Projetc1\bin\x86\Debug\Project1.dll`, which is obvious because we haven't build any project on this server yet...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reboot of the server, it started building fine...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your project is referencing the dll instead of the dependent project.  If that is the case, msbuild will not be able to determine the build order correctly.

Comment: but I still build fine on fresh computer with visual studio... It is the same `.sln` file.

Comment: Have you tried a clean build using msbuild instead of visual studio?  I've seen where the two don't always behave the same when it comes to finding dependencies.

Comment: yes, and it builds fine... It even builds with VS2010 express.